# When it's correct to use nested controllers in AngularJS, and when not?

Tags: design-patterns, angularjs

I'm a beginner in AngularJs, so maybe I'm missing something important, but I think that if we want to share information between controllers, we can use a service instead, isn't it?.

Controllers should not know about the view (html), but if you think it, when we use nested controllers like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerA">
...
   <div ng-controller="ControllerB"> 
   ...
   </div>
</div>
```

and if the ControllerB use the ControllerA scope, then we are just coupling ControllerB with ControllerA and the view (html), because the html here determine the hierarchy of the scopes in the controllers, If we want to change all the html with a new design for example, and the html structure change like this:

```
<div ng-controller="ControllerA">
...
</div>

<div ng-controller="ControllerB">
...
</div>
```

Then this changes in the view also affect our ControllerB logic too (because it use the ControllerA scope), so to me, nested controllers in AngularJS looks like an antipattern, but maybe I'm missing something, so..

When it's correct to use nested controllers in AngularJs, and when not?

Could you give me some use cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the controller hierarchy is a side effect of the HTML layout, that is true.

I can think of two times where it is intrinsic to the function, however. One is for example the ng-repeat directive. The child scopes inherit from the parent and this is correct because you'd want a parent scope to control the children as a set.

The second is in logical units. In other words, if I am building a set of pages for products, I might create a parent products controller and then child controllers for selecting products, adding products, deleting products. This is a logical relationship that is independent of the view implementation. Doing this, however, makes sense because now I can set up my UI in multiple ways without side effects. For example, maybe I default to a grid view with a list and then use routes to transition to the details view - that will work. Or I may decide to put the selection on the left side of the same page and the details on the right - same thing will work. I can test and coordinate those controllers but while I have a logical inheritance it does not impose a hierarchy on the way the UI is implemented.

If I have unrelated controllers but a common "global concern" or what we would call an "aspect" then I'll use a service and instead of worrying about controller hierarchy deal with interacting with that service instead.